# Binary file doesn't get loaded in Radgrid

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, telerik-grid, .net-4.8

I'm loading data in a telerik:RadGrid, but I have one column that is not loading, which includes files (binary data).

As you can see in the image, instead of loading DB content, this column just loads `System.Byte`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJYti.png)

My current bound code is standard

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="FileContent" 
         FilterControlAltText="Filter por conteudo de ficheiro"        
         HeaderText="Ficheiro">`
```

Any ideas on how to load the intended content?

Comment: What does the bytes make up, is it an image file? A sound file? Encrypted data?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen There are excel files

Comment: Well, the grid not going to render excel inside of each cell. You have to provide a button click or some such to then get the row, and then stream the excel byte data down to the client browser. So you can't display, and really don't want to include the bytes column in that grid - it can't be displayed anyway, so remove it from the grid display.  If you want to have some button click to get or download the Excel sheet, then that is a massive part of your question you left out, right? but even if that is your question, yo have to remove that column from the grid - it can't display excel.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Yeah, it is more complex that i thought.. I understand your explanation, will work on it

Comment: Well, edit your question. Just state that I have rows of data in a grid, and I want the user to select particular row to feach out a byte binary column I have in the database that is a excel file. So, I would drop in a button for that cell - maybe a image button with  a Excel logo. When you click on it, it will stream down the bytes to the browser. You can choose to have this result in a download file, or actually have browser direct open the sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the telrick gird. But we can display each row, and for each row say have a button on it. When you click on that button, it can downloads that bytes() column from the browser to the client computer.

So, say we have this:

```
        <div style="width:40%">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="FileName"        />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MineType" HeaderText="MineType"        />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"  />

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdExcel" runat="server" Height="48px" Width="48px" 
                                ImageUrl="~/Content/excel.png"
                                OnClick="cmdExcel_Click" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Our database has a column called FileB (byes of the excel file).

So, we can load up the grid, but NOT include the Excel file. But, we did place a button in the grid as per above.

So, code to fill the grid can look like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT ID, FileName, MineType, Description FROM tblFiles";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        DataTable rst = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
            conn.Open();
            rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rst;
    }
```

And now we have this:

[image]

Note in a above how we not only saved the file name, but ALSO saved the "mine" type. .net 4.5 (or later) has a built in function called GetMineType - you can pass it a file name, and it will produce the correct mine type.

So, in above, when you click on the "image button", then we have this code to fetch the bytes from the database, and send it to the client:

```
  protected void cmdExcel_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)sender;

        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)btn.Parent.Parent;
        int PKID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"];

        // get data from table
        DataRow rstData = MyRst("SELECT FileB, FileName, MineType from tblFiles where ID = " + PKID).Rows[0];
        Byte[] binFile = (Byte[])rstData["FileB"];

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();

        Response.ContentType = rstData["MineType"].ToString();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + rstData["FileName"]);

        Response.BinaryWrite(binFile);

        Response.End();

    }
```

As noted, most grids, be they gridview, list view or that telerick grid should work similar. So you don't include the bytes() data in the grid, but allow a button click, and stream down (send) the byte file to the client.